# Dual boot win 10 and ubuntu 20.04, bluetooth stop working in ubuntu after boot windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows, bluetooth

I have dual boot with win 10 and ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Every time I boot windows and then boot ubuntu my bluetooth doesn't connect to my headset JBL TUNE500BT. I tried to use bluetoothctl, it
connects, but then disconnects.

```
Attempting to connect to B8:F6:53:F6:86:0F
[CHG] Device B8:F6:53:F6:86:0F Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

The issue seems to resolve when I reboot ubuntu a certain number of times, although always come again when I boot windows.

`sudo service bluetooth restart` not seems to work.

I've tried several things by now, please help. what can i do?

Comment: Do you use suspend?  Have you disabled "fast startup" in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your device from auto-connect list.

Try putting below in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2; echo "connect B8:F6:53:F6:86:0F" | bluetoothctl
```

2 is the seconds, you can increase the number to allow computer to boot up completely.

Right-click on it, and if 'Is executable' not selected, select it.
Add it to startup programs (Settings - Startup and Shutdown - Autostart)

(If you save it on desktop, you can click on it whenever you need to connect)

This works if your device id is correct.
Check `hcitool dev` and `hcitool scan` to see if it is.
(hcitool might not be installed, you might need to find the appropriate command for your bluetooth package or install hcitool)